# Prevent dev branch from being worked on locally

Tags: git, git-flow

I make this mistake ALL THE TIME. I have my integration branch checked out locally, and I develop on it by accident. In the gitflow model, you basically should never do that. Is there some way to lock the dev/integration branch locally so that I don't accidentally develop on it? I need to have a copy of the dev branch locally to do merges etc...or maybe I just need `origin/dev`, not `dev`?

One problem - if I use this:

```
git fetch origin dev:dev
```

I thought that would update my local `origin/dev` branch only, but it actually updates my dev branch as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), which will be run by git whenever you try to commit; if it returns a nonzero status code, the commit won't be allowed to happen. Put this in `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and make the file executable:

```
if [[ `git symbolic-ref HEAD` == "refs/heads/your-integration-branch" ]]; then exit 1; fi
```

Comment: not a bad solution, but I would prefer to not have the dev branch exist at all locally, so that I never even make any changes on it ever.

Comment: My only idea off the top of my head is to use the `post-checkout` hook to print a warning message if you check out that branch.

Comment: so once you make changes, but can't commit them, can you please talk about how to use git stash to move the changes to another branch?

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman: That should simply be `git stash push; git checkout correct-branch; git stash pop`.